# How to not associate a controller with a view? [Grails]

Tags: java, api, grails

I am working on a Grails app that only consumes a third-party API and uses Firebase as a datastore. Because of this, I don't want to associate my controller methods with any views in the `grails-app/views` directory. I keep getting a `ServletException: could not resolve view in servlet` whenever any controller methods gets called back. How should I stop this from happening?

Comment: This will largely depend on the code in the controller. By default if you do not specify what to render it will attempt to render a view by the same name as the method under the directory within the views matching that of the controller name. Post an example of your controller method and we can help you understand what your options are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Groovy if the last statement of the method is implicitly the return statement. Similarly, in Grails, a controller action method will expect a view with the same name as your method name if you do not explicitly render a view.

With that in mind, you can solve this in two ways.

1. Create an empty view that matches the method name with nothing in it.
2. Render an empty string as the last statement in your method as such.

   ```
   class SomeController{

       def index(){
          // do stuff
          render ""
      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to render anything, you likely need to render a status at the end of the method. You can do so like this: `render(status: 200)`